# JQuery: Self-closing div

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm working against a legacy system which produce self-closing div when the div contains nothing.

I want use jQuery to get inner html of some div, but if the div is self-closing, jQuery always get wrong html.

See the demo code bellow:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var s = $('.b').html();
            alert(s);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b" />
    <div class="c">This is c</div>
</html>
```

When I run this code, I get this result:

[image]

Please help me, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the doctype? If it's not an XHTML doctype, can you force it to use one?

Comment: @tvanfosson: <!doctype html>

Comment: Is there any way to change the doctype so that it matches the standard (XHTML) that the documents are being served with? I would think that the browser would obey the doctype if you set it to a type that matched the document structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is not possible, as per [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/782822) elements ending in a slash are equivalent to ones that don't.

jQuery operates on the DOM the browser generates and the browser sees the element as open, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/DvsCg/):

```
var s = $('.b').parent().html(); // <div class="a"></div><div class="b"><div class="c">This is c</div></div>
```

Comment: Is this is a fault of JQuery? or how we can do to regard the DOM `<div />` as a blank one?

Comment: @jesse No, this is not jQuery's fault, it is the browsers fault neither, it is the fault of the programmer of this legacy system. I don't think the issue can be easily circumvented either.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer, I see, does it means that we should create a blank DOM like `<div></div>` instead of `<div />` when it is necessary?

Comment: @jesse Yes. Only an explicit close works in HTML 5 (or everything except XHTML), unless the element is self closing (or **Void** as the W3C calls them)

Comment: @TimWolla: Lucky the legacy system's html has fixed format, and the second div rarely contains a div like the third div. So I solve my problem in this way: 
    var s = $('.b').html().trim();
    if(s.indexOf('<div class="c">') == 0){
        s = '';
    }